# Vertical align not works

Tags: css

I had a few hours of looking for the solution of this problem and now I'm gonna ask you.
So, I'd like to position a text left to an image. The image should float to the right and the text to the left but vertically aligned. I know I have to align the image to the text but it's not working. Here's my code:

CSS:

```
div.sale {
text-align: left;
}

div.sale img {
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
clear: right;
}
```

And the other parts:

```
<div class="sale">
<img src="imagelink" alt="" width="150" height="150">
<span style="height: 75px;">simply text</span>
</div>
```

I'd be glad if you can help me!

Best regards!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you show an image of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vertically center the text by using `display: table` in combination with the
`vertical-align: middle` property

**Explanation**

- added `display: table` to the outer div, establish table/table-cell relationship
- added `width: 100%` to outer div - so it takes up the full width of the parent container
- added `display: table-cell` to the `span` containing the text
- Because its a table, the order of `span#text` and `div.sale img` matters, so I put text before image
- apply `vertical-align: middle;` to the `div.sale span` element

Here is a working **demo** - http://jsbin.com/yurajijuxi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This is exactly what I want my dear Michael! Thanks for the help!

Best regards,

Zoli